# Could lack of ram cause image processing to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, rmagick

I have a 512MB Rackspace box on which I'm running 3 websites written using Ruby on Rails (4500-5000 visits per month).

I'm using Carrierwave and RMagick to resize images I upload to the sites but this has recently stopped working with a generic error (Image failed to be processed).

I'm at a loss as to why this would suddenly fail and can only think it started when I deployed app #3. Could the amount of RAM be causing image processing to fail?

Thanks

Robin

Comment: Have you monitored the RAM usage?

Comment: Having some difficulty SSH-ing into the server at the moment which has led me down this thought process...

Answer (score 0):

Robin -

Try Mini_magick gem.  I've heard that resizing images in rmagick can take up to 100MB so if doing things like many thumbnails could cause memory problems esp. on shared host sites.  Mini_magick works with both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick libraries and uses Mogrify to run via command-line so takes less memory.

However, I couldn't use mini-magick since Imagelists don't appear to be supported and this is what I need.

https://github.com/minimagic/minimagick

Kindest regards,
Mark